# Как изменить размер изображения до определенного размера(мегабайт)

Tags: python

Есть исходное изображение **5мб**. Как его уменьшить до **1мб**?

Алгоритм примерно такой

```
while (изображение !=2мб)
{
     изображение =уменьшитьФото(величина);
     величина++;
}
```

Comment: Нужно именно точное значение размера, или всё таки условие размер "в пределах"? И какой формат изображения?

Comment: И в первой строке у Вас 1Мб, а в "коде" - 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
import os

def getSize(filename):
    st = os.stat(filename)
    return st.st_size

with Image.open("1.jpg", 'r') as source:
    quality = 100
    source.save('target.jpg', quality=quality, optimize=True, progressive=True)
    while getSize('target.jpg') > 2000000:
        source.save('target.jpg', quality=quality-1, optimize=True, progressive=True)
        quality -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def JPEGSaveWithTargetSize(im, filename, target):
   Qmin, Qmax = 25, 96
   Qacc = -1
   while Qmin <= Qmax:
      m = math.floor((Qmin + Qmax) / 2)

      # Encode into memory and get size
      buffer = io.BytesIO()
      im.save(buffer, format="JPEG", quality=m)
      s = buffer.getbuffer().nbytes

      if s <= target:
         Qacc = m
         Qmin = m + 1
      elif s > target:
         Qmax = m - 1

   # Write to disk at the defined quality
   if Qacc > -1:
      im.save(filename, format="JPEG", quality=Qacc)
   else:
      print("ERROR: No acceptble quality factor found", file=sys.stderr)
```

А вот пример использования. Сохраняем в 1мб-ный файл

```
im = Image.open(os.path.join(imgfolder,img))
JPEGSaveWithTargetSize(im, "tmp.jpg", 1000000)
```

Comment: Разве из вопроса понятно, что формат с потерями и требуется уменьшить размер за счёт качества?

Comment: @MBo эмм.. А разве без потери качества можно размер картинки уменьшить?

Comment: Да, изменив физический размер в пикселах. Из исходного вопроса непонятно, что имелось в виду подобрать качество сжатия.

Comment: Скажите, а с какой целью вы задали вопрос, на который сами через пару часов ответили?

Comment: @strawdog, [правилами сайта это не запрещается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).